# How can I force perform an action/compute the DAG of apache spark dataframe and store it in DISK (not memory)?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a series of transformations on a spark dataframe and I am using pyspark to apply my filters and conditions over the dataframe. Due to spark lazy evaluation, these transformations get applied only when an action is performed on the dataframe. I am seeing the spark job getting stuck while writing the final dataframe. So I decided to split the transformation into stages with less number of transformations as below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf

df = spark.read.format('avro').load(<filepath>)

# stage 1
df = df.withColumn('status', sf.lit("true"))
df = df.filter(<some_condition>)
# some filter operations
df.write.format('avro').save(<temp_location>)

# stage 2
df = spark.read.format('avro').load(<temp_location>)
# some filter operations and transformations
df.write.format('avro').save(<temp_location>)

# stage 3
df = spark.read.format('avro').load(<temp_location>)
# some filter operations and transformations
df.write.format('avro').save(<temp_location>)
```

This is how I am trying to breakdown the entire list of my operations into smaller chunks and then evaluating them at specific intervals since performing entire list of operations at same time is causing memory issues/hung

Can I make use of any inbuilt functionality of spark to force an action or compute the result till that point and store it (so DAG gets cleared) and next step can start using it rather than computing all the previous transformations from the start?

Will caching with `DISK` level persistence help here?

Comment: How big is your data? What parameters are you using? Actions are sequential unless using .par type approach but this is pyspark, may be different.

Comment: @newbie, did you figure out any alternative/result for your question so far? I am in a similar situation and have a similar need also.

Comment: @ylcnky yes, using `checkpoint` of spark to get the above functionality